# Ionic - how to add certificate into Network security config?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

after my latest Ionic app publish, the Android version cannot connect to my API, which is on https (but iOS version of the app is fine). I tried to change API calls to http, but store refused it as unsecured user data transfer.  Changing targetSdk to 27 helped, but again, after uploding on store it was refused right away with message, that APK files must have at least targetSdk v28.

This connection problem happening only on a build with --release flag and only on Android 9.0 and above. By debugging I am not getting any error message, but the Android just won't connect to my API. I don't want to buy new certificate, as I have RapidSSL cert right now for 2 years and it works fine for iOS and on Android below v9.0.

My problem is, I want to add my pem certificate used on API into the netwrok_security_config.xml as I am being told here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.

So that file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">0.0.0.0</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">(my domain IP address)</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">(my domain)</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca/cert.pem"/>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I've tried the .pem I have on server and even the .crt I have on server, still the same result.
In the config.xml I also added this file as resource file, so it is in the generated platform folder under res folder:
`<resource-file src="resources/android/raw/my_ca/cert.pem" target="app/src/main/res/raw/my_ca/cert.pem" />`

And also this line , which is for Android >9.0 being able make HTTP connection, but just in case:
`<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />`

With this seemingly fine settings I am getting build error:

> network_security_config.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource raw/my_ca/cert.pem (aka com.myionicproject.app:raw/my_ca/cert.pem) not found.

When I try putting into certificate src only path to folder as they say on the Android documentation  I am getting error: “resource file cannot be a directory”.

When I try to link it with relative path, the build throws warning that in netwrok_security_config.xml file the certificate tag src attribute can only have values system, user or @resource. Yet it builds fine, but after turning on the app and creating API request, the app just crashes every time.

Btw. I also used Charles proxy for debugging, and after installing their .pem certificate into the phone and running the app, the app worked perfectly, as the proxy trusted the ssl on the server I guess.
The app is published on a store for over a year now, it worked without any problems until I switched to ionic 4 recently.
I couldn't find someone already dealing with this, having Ionic and putting their cert into the network configuration xml. Does anybody here have some experience with this?
 Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was server-side and in the end I removed the certificates stuff from the network_security_config.xml. After I put my https api link into SSL checker (https://ssltools.digicert.com/checker/views/checkInstallation.jsp) it told me that I don't have the Intermediate certificate. I had one on the server, but only .pem file, I found out that I need Intermediate .crt as well, so I downloaded the Digicert's Intermediate (in .txt), change the file extension to .crt and put it on server with new line in Apache config:
`SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/myproject/intermediate.crt`
restarted and now it works.

Only on Android devices with version 9+ it caused problems, and only on production (built with --release flag)

Answer (score 0):

For Android, my network_security_config looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://somedomain.com/</domain> 
        <pin-set expiration="2020-10-03">
            <pin digest="SHA-256">server pin</pin>
        </pin-set>      
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And my SDKs are

```
defaultMinSdkVersion=19 
defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 
defaultCompileSdkVersion=28
```

And its working fine.I'm using Ionic 3. 
BTW, I'm also looking for iOS SSL pinning.

Comment: How did u generate server pin